# linked server operation

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert rows from server1.table1 to server2.table2. I already create a linked server in order to query tables in both servers and it works.

However because server2.table2 has an identity column,and though I put the hint `set identity_insert table2 on`,
  the insert operation failed and I got the following errors in french:

```
L'objet "192.168.0.36.wt_delivery.dbo.table2" est introuvable, car il n'existe pas ou vous ne disposez pas des autorisations requises.
```

which mean that the object 192.168.0.36.wt_delivery.dbo.table2 is not found or we don't have the required permission to do the operation.

when I create the same table without the identity column the insert operation succeed!!

The query was executed from server1

Is there a specific permission that allow the operation to succeed or the problem is not at permission level?

Thank you

Comment: It's not a permission issue.  You can't specify the value for an identity column.  You can still make that column be the primary key and/or clustered index, however.

Comment: When you wrote `set identity_insert table2 on` did you qualify it with server and schema name? I never tried to do indentity_insert across linked server.

Comment: You can specify the value for an identity column, provided that you set identity_insert on, as Op as has mentioned here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft documentation indicates that you can only use a 3-part naming convention for the [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) command.

> SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . ] table { ON | OFF }

Somebody else had this same issue, and [provided a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391744/identity-insert-on-linked-server-fails) using a temp table, and remote stored procedure to do the work.

Comment: Yes I already did it with a temp table but I was surprised that we cannot do it directly with the set identity_insert clause.

Comment: It's certainly unfortunate. Using a remote procedure is a good workaround. You might want to consider creating a Connect item with Microsoft to see if they would put that in the product.